# AngularJS overwrites isolated directive scope

Tags: angularjs, scope, directive

Usage:

```
<my-directive my-var="true"></my-directive>
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('myDirective', [
    function () {
        var definition = {
            restrict: "E",
            replace: false,
            transclude: false,
            scope: {
                myVar: '@',
            },
            controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
                console.log($scope.myVar); // "true"
                $scope.myVar = "false";
                console.log($scope.myVar); // "false"

                setTimeout(function() {
                    console.log($scope.myVar); // "true" (!)
                }, 100);
            }]
        };

        return definition;
    }
]);
```

Console output

```
"true"
"false"
"true"
```

What is exactly happening here? The variable is passed as string ("true"), I'm changing it, then it get's replaced again? I would like to understand the cycle here. Is this because there is some additional compilation or digest cycle kicking in and recalculating all isolated scope values again? I  thought that once set, variables passed like this (@, just string in directive) would stay the same?

Is there any way to hook up within directive to a moment, after which string variables are not replaced, or will it always work like this with every digest or whatnot, and I'm forced to use $watch?

Comment: This is related to similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22967024/initializing-isolated-scope-inside-a-directive, but I don't find the original answer to be complete, because I use eval to reevaluate these string into booleans, don't really want to change their value, but to make them stay boolean. So I translate one to boolean, and then it gets overriden to string again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`@` binds the parent scope to the isolated scope and it's a one-way (not one-time) binding. So, any change in the outer scope will reset the value in the directive's isolate scope.

[Under the covers](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.2/src/ng/compile.js#L1897), Angular calls `attrs.$observe` on the element attribute with "@". What this does is that it queues an observer function for the next $digest cycle after the compilation. That observer function is what sets the scope variable every time there is a change in the interpolated value assigned to the attribute.

So, the high-level steps are:

```
1) for `@` scope variable, set an observer function and queue it for later
2) set `@` scope variable to the interpolated value
3) run the controller, pre- and post-link functions
...
N) observer runs against interpolated value and sets the scope value
```

So, given this, you can now see why your change didn't persist. It would, if you made it after all of these steps - i.e. with a timeout or in response to an event. And *only* if the attribute interpolated value hasn't changed.

This is NOT so with "`=`".

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZFJlexrWISbL3s71woGv?p=preview) illustrating the differences.

If you want a one-time passage of variables, just set the scope variable using an attribute in the link function or the controller

```
scope.myVar = $attrs["my-var"];
```

and remove `myVar` from the scope.

Comment: What else are you looking for? It answers your question. Why does it change? - because it's a one-way binding, i.e. any change in parent scope variable will cause a change in the bound isolate scope variable. In your question, you made an incorrect assumption that it wouldn't.

Comment: I know that there's binding established. What I don't know (and want to know), what exactly triggers the digest cycle reevaluation, so that it populates new object again, even if it did before and its value didn't change. These are kind of deep internal things.

Comment: $digest cycle is started whenever any component calls `$scope.$apply`. It also goes down and up the hierarchy on first run. If you know about binding then you know that it is done using dirty checking - because you changed the value between the runs it re-applied the binding. See my own question and the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25908745/968155)

Comment: Yes, I also do know that, thank you. The point is that the value is changed long after all the initialization. No other component on the site I know of also forces any new digests and yet the value changes, so there has to be something. I was wondering what it could possibly be, but maybe the question is too vague after all.

Comment: Not vague. I ran some experiments and not everything was exactly how I thought it would be, so I had to take a closer look into Angular's code. I updated the answer.