# Angular parsing directive element parameter as json string has some delay

Tags: angularjs

Hello here is an example which describe that problem:
http://jsbin.com/bewelureve/edit?html,js,console,output
As can be seen, if we put json as income parameter, looks like it has some delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I have recently found the explanation of that behavior here:
[AngularJS overwrites isolated directive scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26679281/angularjs-overwrites-isolated-directive-scope)
Looks like the $observe reset income values which were specified through interpolation. 
Thanks for all guys.